# using docker with VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new on docker and now I start learning from this tutorial:
https://docker-curriculum.com/#getting-started

my local machine is windows 10 and I use openstack VM Ubuntu-18.04-LTS for the docker tutorial and everything is going OK until I run the docker web image and try to open the web page    http://localhost:32769 on my local browser and It give me: **This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.**

Comment: Can you share the outupt of executing `docker ps` ?

Comment: with local browser you mean your windows 10 machine or within your ubuntu VM?

Comment: @ClemensKaserer I mean the Windows machine

Comment: You will not be able to access the container's exported port 80 from Windows. It is only available to the Linux VM. See the second part of my answer below. If you wanted to access the port from Windows, you would have to configure port forwarding in openstack accordingly. Not sure if/how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the tutorial you are following assumes that your docker installation is on your workstation. That is not the case in your setup. You have to destinct machines. Your workstation and your docker host.

With localhost you can only connect to the machine that you are currently working on. In your case that would be your workstation. Since you do not have docker running on your workstation and did not execute the commands in the tutorial in your workstation `localhost` will not work. There is nothing there to connect to.

So in order to get you up and running you need

- IP of your docker host (your ubuntu machine)
- the correct port that your container is exposed on the ubuntu VM

you can get the IP via (executed on your ubuntu VM)

```
ifconfig
```

and you can check the port that has been exposed by executing (on your ubuntu VM)

```
docker port static-site
```

Once you have got the IP of your Ubuntu VM and the exposed Port you can access the container from your windows workstation by entering

```
http://[UBUNTU VM IP]:[EXPOSED PORT]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ip address of docker instead of localhost to see the webpage.

Following command will help to find the docker ip

```
$ docker-machine ip
```

using the obtained ip, you can hit the url.

```
http://<Obtained IP>:<port>
```

Comment: The port the container exports is 80 - not 32769. 32769 is the randomized local port number. The correct URL would be: `http://<Obtained IP>:80`. As 80 is the default for HTTP, it should be OK to remove it from the URL and just go with `http://<Obtained IP>`.

Comment: when run docker-machine ip  it give me : Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists

Comment: @FaDATA, you need to provide machine name in the command i.e. `$ docker-machine ip <machine name>`

Answer (score 0):

2 possible issues:

- Please show the output of the command `docker port static-site`. The container's ports are bound randomly to your local host. You will most likely have to use a port different from what is used in the example.
  The example output is `80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769` and the URL derived from that is http://localhost:32769
- The port will be bound in your Ubuntu VM. You will not be able to access it from Windows browser.

Comment: docker port static-site  443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32769

Comment: why I can't access it from windows browser?  the other applications that I run it on Vm without docker I can open it on the local windows browser

Answer (score 0):

When you run your container, you need to expose your container on a port so that the traffic from outside could reach to your container. Having the EXPOSE port  in the container image tells that the container runs and bind to that particular port internally.

He has exposed the container to 32769 port number, so he need to use this port on the browser.

Comment: You can check if the firewall at your machine is blocking you at this port, try it from Mobile browser.